# Using JWT token in ASP.NET Web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication, bearer-token, jwt

An ASP.NET web-forms based application, follows form authentication, maintains user session in DB for stateless model across the servers(F5 DR). Planning to replace the session management with JWT token based to avoid db hits and to meet future API development but the UI (aspx) will be remain as it is.

Question: When it comes to ASP.NET webform which would execute all the requests at server side,posting a token between browser (client) and IIS (server) could be server-side processing (managed in ASP.NET context but not like a SPA), I assume it may behave like an in-proc session, that means it would NOT meet stateless model requirement across the servers. Any suggestions? Does token-model not suit for asp.net web app?